# Select data within a time period by Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, time, count

I am trying to count/select the data field within a time period. When using the following format, where I explicit specify the whole timestamp, the query is correct.

```
SELECT TimeStamp,strftime('%Y',TimeStamp) as "Year",
strftime('%m',TimeStamp) as "Month",
strftime('%d',TimeStamp) as "Day",
strftime('%M',TimeStamp) as "Minute",
strftime('%H', TimeStamp) as "Hours"
FROM temp
WHERE TimeStamp between '2017-12-22T20:50:00' and '2017-12-23T21:00:00'
```

What I tried to do is select field with timestamp within a certain hours. So I modify my query as:

```
SELECT TimeStamp,strftime('%Y',TimeStamp) as "Year",
strftime('%m',TimeStamp) as "Month",
strftime('%d',TimeStamp) as "Day",
strftime('%M',TimeStamp) as "Minute",
strftime('%H', TimeStamp) as "Hours"
FROM temp
WHERE strftime('%H', TimeStamp) between 20 and 21
```

Then the query returns 0 row, where do I do wrong ? 
My timestamp format follows the sqlite convention as YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.3u.
Here is an example for my timestamp: 2017-12-22T20:57:02.188Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT TimeStamp,strftime('%Y',TimeStamp) as "Year",
strftime('%m',TimeStamp) as "Month",
strftime('%d',TimeStamp) as "Day",
strftime('%M',TimeStamp) as "Minute",
strftime('%H', TimeStamp) as "Hours"
FROM temp
WHERE cast(strftime('%H', TimeStamp) as int) between 20 and 21
```

strftime returns a string, you compare to ints. cast the string as int to solve that

Answer (score 1):

Your instruction `strftime('%H', TimeStamp)` is considered as a string. Thus it can't be compared to integers. You need to explicitly cast it as an int.

```
CAST(strftime('%H', TimeStamp) AS INT)
```